# SQL Order By Desc wrong result

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I want my SQL tables data to be displayed in reverse of what it is in the table. In my SQL Analyzer my SQL gets me the result I want.

(Shortened version of it)

```
SELECT jobpost_id FROM needa_job_employee_cv_jobpost ORDER BY jobpost_id DESC
```

The IDs come out in this order `20;18;7;6;4;` with SQL Analyzer, which is what I want.

But for some reason it comes out `7;6;4;20;18` on my website.

Why does it randomly split the deck(using poker terms)?

If I use response.write to show my how the array is built it comes out in these pieces.

```
7
7;6
7;6;4
7;6;4;20
7;6;4;20;18
```

So how can my SQL start half way through the table, go up, and then add the ones at the end?

```
SELECT jobpost_id FROM needa_job_employee_cv_jobpost
```

Without the Order By it comes out like this `4;6;7;18;20` which the reverse of what I want.

This is done with ASP Classic.

**EDIT ON REQUEST**

My loop that produces the array.

```
DO WHILE NOT getinfo.EOF

getjobpost_id = getjobpost_id & symbol & trim(getinfo("jobpost_id"))


response.Write(getjobpost_id)

symbol = ";"
symboll = "|"

getinfo.MoveNext
loop
```

Comment: is for some reason the `jobpost_id` a `char` field?

Comment: I think the problem is that your website parse the jobpost_id as string and sort strings instead of integers

Comment: No it is an INT and is set as primary key. Thanks for your idea, I did check it.

Comment: can you share that FULL `response.write` code with us problem seems to be in front end.

Comment: See above yogi. Thanks for response.

Comment: Something else is going on. ORDER BY works. Please post full code, not "shortened version" and we'll try to see what might have gone wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of 'jobpost_id'. Or try to convert this column to INT.

ORDER BY COVERT(jobpost_id, unsigned) DESC

Comment: It is INT. Do you mean CONVERT?